# Can we use Graph-ql java client to query over rest

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I have a graph ql server where I wish to run some queries on over rest api using java.

I'm using rest assured to call the POST /graphql api, however I'm trying to understand if I can use the graph gl java client to build queries in a type safe manner if possible.

Right now the only way to build these queries is as string since they're not even formatted jsons.

e.g. {myObject(id: 2) {id name code}}